# How i can filter and return a nested array of object?

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript, nested

someone can help me?
i have a data structure like as:

```
contracts: [ 
0: {closedRequest: [{id: ... , name: ... } , {id: ... , name: ... }, {id: ... , name: ... }]},
1: {closedRequest: [{id: ... , name: ... } , {id: ... , name: ... }, {id: ... , name: ... }]},

]
```

Now i would filter this object for delete element in closedRequest that have a determined Id.
I try to use with filter, but array not change.

How i can do it?

Example, i want exclude all element that have id (on closedRequest) = 3

so, if i have this structure:

```
contracts: [ 
0: {closedRequest: [{id: 2 , name: "a"} , {id: 3 , name: "b"}, {id: 4 , name: "c" }]},
1: {closedRequest: [{id: 2 , name: "a"} , {id: 3 , name: "b"}, {id: 4 , name: "c" }]},

]
```

i want have:

```
contracts: [ 
0: {closedRequest: [{id: 2 , name: "a"}  {id: 4 , name: "c" }]},
1: {closedRequest: [{id: 2 , name: "a"}  {id: 4 , name: "c" }]},

]
```

Example of my code:

```
client.contracts.forEach((c) =>
          c.closedRequests.filter((cr) => cr.requestID != requestID)
        );
```

i want have same object, but with filed of closedRequest edited.

Thanks

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: filter method doesn't change original array. It return a new array with elements for which passed function returns true. It'll be helpful if edit your post to include code.

Comment: ok, i add my code thansk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each item of `contracts` array consists of many fields, you can use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the old array into a new one and [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in order to filter a nested array:

```js
let contracts = [ 
    { closedRequest: [{id: 2 , name: "a"} , {id: 3 , name: "b"}, {id: 4 , name: "c" }] },
    { closedRequest: [{id: 2 , name: "a"} , {id: 3 , name: "b"}, {id: 4 , name: "c" }] }
];

let filteredContracts = contracts.map(contract => 
     ({ ...contract, closedRequest : contract.closedRequest.filter(x => x.id !== 3) }));

console.log(filteredContracts);
```